# callback using self

Tags: rust, callback, traits

I am trying to use a callback that uses the self parameter of an object. The part that prevents this from compiling is the self.make_sandwhich() bit. How can I do something like this and have it actually compile in rust? The objective is to make ThingUser able to specify functionality for a Thing. In this case, when you junk the potato, the user makes a sandwhich.

```
pub trait Thing {
  fn stuff(&self);
  fn junk(&mut self);
}

pub struct Potato {
    thing: Box<dyn FnMut()+Send>,
}

impl Potato {
  fn new() -> Self {
    Self{
        thing: Box::new(||{println!("Original callback");}),
    }
  }
  
  fn give_callback(&mut self, thing: Box<dyn FnMut()+Send>) {
      self.thing = thing;
  }
}

impl Thing for Potato {
  fn stuff(&self) {
  }
  fn junk(&mut self) {
    (self.thing)();
  }
}

fn make_thing() -> Box<dyn Thing> {
    Box::new(Potato::new())
}

pub trait ThingUser {
    fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Box<dyn Thing>>;
}

pub struct Person {
    
}

impl Person {
    fn make_sandwhich(&self) {
        println!("I made a sandwhich");
    }
}

impl ThingUser for Person {
    fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Box<dyn Thing>> {
        let mut p = Potato::new();
        p.give_callback(Box::new(||{self.make_sandwhich()}));
        Some(Box::new(p))
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
  let mut p  = Potato::new();
  p.stuff();
  
  p.give_callback(Box::new(||{println!("Callback");}));
  (p.thing)();
  p.junk();
  
  let mut q = make_thing();
  q.junk();
  
  let mut tu = Person{};
  let used_thing = tu.get_thing();
  used_thing.unwrap().junk();
}
```

Comment: (psst. It's spelled "sandwich")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design you posted cannot work. In `ThingUser::get_thing` it takes `&mut self`, which means that `self` is a borrow of type `&mut dyn ThingUser`. The closure `|| { self.make_sandwhich() }` must also borrow `self` (although it only needs a non-`mut` `&dyn ThingUser` to call `make_sandwhich`). That borrow of `self` must live as long as the closure lives.

However, you want to store the closure inside a `Potato`. This would mean that after storing it the `Potato` is also borrowing `&ThingUser`, but `Potato` is not defined to borrow anything at all (there are no lifetime parameters in the definition of potato). Therefore any closure you will ever be able to pass to `give_callback` *must* have a `'static` lifetime (meaning that it doesn't borrow anything, except possibly things that live for the entire length of the program).

This is what's being expressed by your compiler error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f81f98d4ab35bac5e098d7b4edc19bd))

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:51:25
   |
49 |     fn get_thing(&mut self) -> Option<Box<dyn Thing>> {
   |                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
50 |         let mut p = Potato::new();
51 |         p.give_callback(Box::new(||{self.make_sandwhich()}));
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

The compiler is stopping you from doing this:

```rust
let person = Person {};
let mut potato = Potato::new();
p.give_callback(Box::new(|| { person.make_sandwhich() } ));
drop(person);
potato.junk(); // ! This would be trying to call `person.make_sandwhich()`, but `person` has been dropped! This is a horrible memory safety error!
```

---

Broadly you have two options.

First would be to define `Potato` with a lifetime parameter, but this will get messy quickly as the lifetime parameter will by tied to the potato type and will complicate pretty much every use of `Potato` ever.

The second (probably preferable) option is to make your closure have a `'static` lifetime. This could be done by storing your person in an `Arc<Person>`, for example. Then you use a `move` closure to create a closure which owns an `Arc<Person>`, so that `Person` cannot be dropped until the closure is dropped. For example

```rust
let person = Arc::new(Person {});
let mut potato = Potato::new();
let person_clone = person.clone();  // Not strictly necessary for this simple example, but I'm assuming you might want access to `person` after creating the callback in which case this is necessary
p.give_callback(Box::new(move || { person_clone.make_sandwhich() } ));
drop(person);
potato.junk(); // This is now fine! The first `Arc<Person>` was dropped, but the closure is still holding one so the internal `Person` object has not been dropped. Hooray!
```

P.S. I highly recommend you use `rustfmt` to format your code (ideally on every save). It will make you faster writing it and will help people read it.