# Implementing Template Method Design Pattern in Rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, traits

This actually comes from another case, but is simplified here. Suppose we want to implement the template method design pattern and provide a library with the implementation of the main algorithm and allow users of the library to customize it by implementing the trait. An example of this pattern can be found [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/rust/example).

We would then create a trait like this:

```
trait Command {
    fn open(&mut self, file: &str);
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> bool;
    fn close(&mut self);
}
```

This will create an interface that the library user can implement and the main algorithm, also provided in the library, would then look like this:

```
fn execute<C: Command>(mut command: C, path: &str) -> String {
    command.open(path);
    let mut sink = Sink::new();
    let mut buf = [0u8; 512];
    while command.read(&mut buf) {
        sink.send(&buf);
    }
    command.close();
}
```

Note that in my particular case, this is the the library that I am using and it is simplified to focus on the problem. I have deliberately used the limited sized buffer here, even though it is possible to pass back data in larger chunks and I am sending out the data to some imaginary sink just to illustrate that we have an algorithm that forwards data without storing it. Also note that in contrast to [Template Method in Rust](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/rust/example) this uses `&mut self` rather than `&self`.

We can now implement this template method for reading from a file in this manner:

```
struct ReadFromFile {
    stream: Option<Box<dyn Read>>,
}

impl ReadFromFile {
    fn new() -> ReadFromFile {
        ReadFromFile { stream: None }
    }
}

impl Command for ReadFromFile {
    fn open(&mut self, path: &str) {
        self.stream = Some(Box::new(File::open(path).unwrap()));
    }

    fn close(&mut self) {
        self.stream = None;
    }

    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> bool {
        match &mut self.stream {
            Some(stream) => stream.read(buf).unwrap() > 0,
            None => false,
        }
    }
}
```

The main function for driving this could look like this:

```
fn main() {
    let read_all = ReadFromFile::new();
    let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
    let result = execute(read_all, &args[1]);
    println!("result: {:?}", result);
}
```

This works fine and all goes well. Now, suppose that we want to read the data from PostgreSQL instead using the [`postgres` crate](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/index.html). Following the pattern from the file example, the implementation would then look like this:

```
struct ReadFromDatabase {
    client: Client,
    stream: Option<Box<dyn Read>>,
}

impl ReadFromDatabase {
    fn new() -> Result<ReadFromDatabase, postgres::Error> {
        let client = Client::connect("host=localhost user=mats", NoTls)?;
        Ok(ReadFromDatabase {
            client,
            stream: None,
        })
    }
}

impl Command for ReadFromDatabase {
    fn open(&mut self, path: &str) {
        let stmt = format!("COPY {} TO stdout", path);
        self.stream = Some(Box::new(self.client.copy_out(&stmt).unwrap()));
    }

    fn close(&mut self) {
        self.stream = None;
    }

    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> bool {
        match &mut self.stream {
            Some(stream) => stream.read(buf).unwrap() > 0,
            None => false,
        }
    }
}
```

However, when compiling this, we get the following error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> examples/template-method.rs:74:28
   |
72 |     fn open(&mut self, path: &str) {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
73 |         let stmt = format!("COPY {} TO stdout", path);
74 |         self.stream = Some(Box::new(self.client.copy_out(&stmt).unwrap()));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Looking for other cases, revealed [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72063505/callback-using-self), which is pretty close to the problem above, where you need to set a callback function.

However, the problem is focused on using a closure and suggested solution have two alternatives: add lifetimes to `ReadFromDatabase` (but it does not elaborate on how), or move the object into the closure. Since this example does not have a closure, it is more difficult to follow that advice.

I think the problem here is that the `stream` can outlive the `client` and for that reason the code protects against an imaginary `execute` method that calls `read` after calling `close`.

The problem is similar to how to handle self-referential structs in the same manner as "A type with a reference to itself" in the reply by [Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) in [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

```
struct WhatAboutThis<'a> {
    name: String,
    nickname: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

Only difference here is that we are storing a reference to a trait, which is not `Sized`, and the canonical way to make it sized is to wrap it in a `Box`.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it possible to write a `ReadFromDatabase` implementation by adding lifetimes and how would that look? I've made a few attempts, but as [JMAA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956078/jmaa) states, it "quickly becomes messy", so I am not sure it is possible to do in a reasonable way.
2. Is there a better pattern for implementing `ReadFromDatabase` without having to change `Command`?

Comment: Adding lifetimes is not the way to go. It creates a [self-referential struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct), and this is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: It depends. Creating a struct with one `postgres::Client` and some prepared `postgres::Statement` is both doable and sensible. More dynamic cases are tricky, and the case you point to is a good discussion about the problems with self-referential structs.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the only way to achieve this in Rust as of the time of this answer (without nightly/experimental features) would require slightly changing signatures of methods that reference `&self` in `Command` traits/implementations.

Signatures can be adjusted to remove self-references, accepting the command as a parameter (instead of expecting it to be `self`): `open(command: &mut dyn SomeTrait, path: &str)`.

Fair to note that `&mut dyn Trait` can create complexities down the line (like explicit lifetime management, etc). This complexities can be avoided for the cost of some performance (if not optimized away) with some `Arc` and `Mutex` abstractions:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn open(command: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>, path: &str);
```

Comment: Is there any experimental features that would help with this case? Given that the design pattern is recommended but fails for this case, it would also be sensible to offer an alternative way to implement that pattern.

Comment: @MatsKindahl, there are two alternatives, in my mind:


1. Use advanced traits. `trait Command<TCmd=Self> { fn open(command: &mut TCmd, path: &str) }`.


2. Write macros for `impl`'s of commands, which inject necessary bits.